# cannot set project's JavaScript Build Path in PHP- eclipse

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse

I have created a php project in eclipse and trying to set up the javascript Build Path after enabling javascript support for the project

The problem arises because the instruction to set up the path does not match what i see in the actual IDE help page

1. in the fisrt image as you can see the highlighted line says 
                         **select properties | Javascript | Javascript libraries**.
   But there is no **Javascript libraries** field here, as you can see in the third image
2. in the second image you can see the highlighted instruction that says **click "add a Runtime library"**, again "add a Runtime library" field is missing from the third image

This means i cannot setup the Javascript built path.
I guess the i must be missing something, so i need some help on setting up this javascript built path. i have been stuck here for days now.

Many thanks for any helps

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are some seriously outdated instructions.

Comment: please can you let me know how to get the up to date instructions for this setup.  Actually i am surprised it is out of date because it is the latest IDE download - just a couple of days ago - so i expected the latest instructions to be in its help

Answer (score 0):

The dialogs had their text cleaned up years ago, but you're in the right place. Adding a "JavaScript Library" adds a single file; a "Library Folder" does so for an entire folder (tree) of JS files. If it helps, a Library Folder is basically just like a Source Folder, only there's no validation done on its contents.

Comment: The issue is how to set a javascript built path for the current php project. It is said that this is required.     I still can't figure out how to do this from your answer

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding where the gap is. What's setting the "JavaScript Build Path" mean to you--what's the end goal?

Comment: I am new to this environment. But the goal is to write a project in the eclipse-php with javascript code in the same environment without having to move between different IDEs, so in eclipse-php they say you have to enable javascript when you create the project (no problem with that) and "JavaScript built path must be set" (this is the problem). I Geuss this means that the php environment would then automatically see the javascript source in the same environment

Comment: this is an extract from the IDE
"The JavaScript build process scans all files, folders, projects and libraries that are on the project's JavaScript Build Path so that resources which are referenced in the project can be made available for Content Assist options . The required resources must therefore be included in the JavaScript Build Path.
JavaScript's Build Path allows you to.... automatically scanning all referenced projects and libraries, configuring the JavaScript Build Path allows you to select which resources will be scanned, and so can significantly speed up the build process."

Comment: Nothing about those mechanisms have changed in a significant way. If you're working in JavaScript, make sure the folders that contain it are marked as Source Folders in the Include Path.